# Setting Liquibase Java use changelogs outside of the classpath/jar

Tags: liquibase

I'm using Liquibase with Maven in a project - v4.2.0.

My changelogs are on the file system, rather than in the JAR or classpath of the project.

I'm using the following to establish my object:

```
liquibase = new Liquibase( changeLogFile, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database );
```

where the `changelogFile` is something like `~/liquibase-sql/changelog/db.changelog.xml`

When I call `liquibase.validate()`, I get the following, after a reminder of the classpath locations:

```
Specifying files by absolute path was removed in Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath parameter.
```

I've tried various things including a `file:` prefix, and the file is question can be opened in terminal directly.
I have looked through the code and I'm confused by the concept of `FileSystemResourceAccessor` being named as such if it can only use the classpath (there's already a `ClassLoaderResourceAccessor`), but I can't see a way to make it work.

Based on very very old questions people have managed this before, but I assume prior to 4.0? *(this works fine on 3.10.3)*

Does anyone have any pointers?  I've used CLI liquibase and understand the error, but I'm not sure how I can *not* determine the path without it being absolute, on the understanding that this would be potentially be ran on a few different machines in arbitrary locations.

This might be niche question, but thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So, you can't set changelogFile = "..\<whateverPath>"?  Why?  Note ~ is also not absolute, it resolves to home path right?  I guess I am not understanding why you don't sync your changelog and then refer to it relative to where you are running from.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using spring boot with liquibase 4.x.x. My changelogs are in the filesystem and not part of the application and any change to the path results in the same error. Where you able to solve it?

Comment: @Cerbis I must have done somewhere, but it's been 6 months now and I'm not using Liquibase currently.
I was making a GUI for Liquibase that would basically do a lot of stuff the CLI doesn't do, using the Liqubase classes, and I must have found a way of making it work - I'm just not currently able to see how I did it from looking at my repo (as noted, been a while).  I'll try and see if I get some free time.

Comment: @ChrisJ - would love to hear if you could remember how you got around this? I recently upgraded a project to latest spring-boot (2.6.8 at time of writing), and as part of that liquibase 4.10.0 also came in - and bang, suddenly tests are failing because liquibase can't load the changelog anymore (because it is sitting outside resource folder, and thus outside the classpath). Till this point, all was fine with using the `file:` prefix for the change-log config setting

Comment: @demaniak - it's deep in my brain somewhere, but it's been nearly a year and a half.   I was attempting to make a simple SB-based GUI for Liquibase, as the Java libs seem to unlock a lot more functionality than the CLI.  I think I solved the answer in there, but it was very hacky.  Feel free to look/contribute/investigate: https://github.com/c-jack/guile/

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I ended up doing (for a gradle-based project):

- force the external location to actually be part of the classpath
- changed the XSD location to full URL (apparently liquibase has enough smarts to NOT fetch that from online location, but instead load from the cache of XSD files bundled with the distribution JAR.

For gradle, this meant adding some stuff to build.gradle like so:

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    //whatever else you have
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/test/resources'
      srcDir 'top-external-folder-of-changelog'
    }
  }
}    
dependencies {
  testImplementation files (path/to/external/folder)
}
```

The changelog schemaLocation attribute then looks like this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.11.xsd"
```

Remember to adjust for your version,

My specific issues was with tests.
For real environments, the liquibase scripts are applied to the database via an external (liquibase-based) tool.

Comment: Another problem that I have is if I want to use the same folder both for testing and running the application it will throw an exception with a message that says: master.xml find twice in the main and test folders!!
my Gradle is something like this:
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      srcDir 'liquibase'
    }
  }
  test {
    resources {
      srcDir 'liquibase'
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I would like to react to **putting scripts outside of classpath/jar**. I took a look around because we wanted to do this as well.

From my point of view, I would say it is not a good approach because anyone can go to the location of the scripts and touch these files which can cause Liquibase to fail. Except that you can go and put any script to that location and modify a database.

I think the authors of Liquibase know why there is no straightforward approach to how to do that.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say here.

It is quite normal to keep Liquibase scripts in Git.  You would also have credentials for the database, and shouldn't hard code them, so the concept of the location of the scripts is not an issue - it sounds like there would be several larger issues at hand.

Note that this is only an issue with the Liquibase Java Library, and NOT with the CLI

Answer (score 0):

I am using liquibase 4.5.0 and the below thing worked for me.

```
val database =
        DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
            .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(
                new JdbcConnection(
                    DriverManager.getConnection(
                        jdbcUrl,
                        getPostgresContainerConfig().username(),
                        getPostgresContainerConfig().password())));

new liquibase.Liquibase(
           "analytics/target/classes/create_db.sql",
            new FileSystemResourceAccessor(
                new File("/Users/debrajmanna/code/java/github/sp/src/java/")),
            database);
```

My file was in `/Users/debrajmanna/code/java/github/sp/src/java/analytics/target/classes/create_db.sql`